# How to access enum defined within a struct in C program

Tags: c, struct, enums

I am new to the C language and struggling with how to access enum's within a struct.

My code is the following:

bankHeader.h File

```
struct bankAcct{
 int amount;
 enum typeOfAcc{chck = 0, saving = 1};
 int balance;
}
```

bank.c File

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bankHeader.h"

struct bankAcct test;
test.amount=100;
// I want to be able to get the value within my typeOfAcc
// example something like test.typeOfAcct = "chck" should return 0;
```

I reviewed some of the forms but I dont see anything that was easy to understand or worked.

Comment: You've declared an enumeration, but you haven't made an actual _variable_ to hold the account type. The bankAcct struct currently just has two variables, `amount` and `balance`.

Comment: You only defined an enum type, not a variable of that type

Comment: What you probably want is `enum { chck, saving} typeOfAcc;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `enum` is meant to be local to the `struct`, use an anonymous `enum`:

```
struct bankAcct{
    int amount;
    enum {chck = 0, saving = 1} type_of_acct;
    int balance;
};
```

You could also put a tagged `enum` inside the `struct`:

```
 struct bankAcct{
    int amount;
    enum typeOfAcc {chck = 0, saving = 1} type_of_acct;
    //^this misleadingly puts `enum typeOfAcc` in filescope 
    int balance;
 };
```

but a tagged (as opposed to an anonymous one) inner definition of an enum (or struct or union) will be hoisted. In effect, the latter snippet is just a confusing way of doing:

```
 enum typeOfAcc {chck = 0, saving = 1};

 struct bankAcct{
    int amount;
    enum typeOfAcc type_of_acct;
    int balance;
 };
```

Note that as [peter-reinstate-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150802/peter-reinstate-monica) points out in his comment below, the `chck` and `saving` constants will be "hoisted" regardless of whether or not you choose to use an anonymous embedded enum type.

Comment: https://www.godbolt.org/z/d88rYo and http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p7 in the N1570 draft seem to indicate that enum constants are visible to the end of the file, tagged or not. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, the constants are effectively hoisted regardless. The anon inner enum definition only avoids publishing the `enum typeOfAcc` to the global scope, effectively preventing the type of the member variable from being usable elsewhere.

Comment: Seems like an esoteric debate to me: You can never use an unnamed type, can you? (Not in C, that is; in C++ you may be able to do things with templates or decltype.)

Answer (score 2):

Every field in your struct declaration is in the form

```
type fieldName;
```

With

```
enum typeOfAcc{chck = 0, saving = 1};
```

you have specified the type... but not the field name. That's just like defining a structure in this way

```
struct foo {
    int;
}
```

So, basically, what you need is a field name:

```
struct bankAcct{
    int amount;
    enum typeOfAcc{chck = 0, saving = 1} type;
    int balance;
}
```

You will be able to access it with

```
struct bankAcct var;

printf("%d\n", var.type);
```

---

### Addendum

I would not recommend defining an enumeration inside a struct, first of all for readability reasons. Another reason might be incompatibility with C++: I wasn't able to compile an example C++ code in which the symbols of the inner `enum` were accessed. The following assignment

```
struct bankAcct var;

var.type = chck;
```

raised an error on **gpp** because the symbol `chck` could not be referenced outside the struct definition scope. Even assigning an integer to the enum field lead the compiler to complain, and I could not even perform the casting

```
b.type = (enum typeOfAcc) 1;
```

because an error was raised: the `enum typeOfAcc` wasn't be accessible as well.

**But in C these assignments would be ok**, and both enum tags and constant identifiers (named and anonymous) would be "reachable". As explained in [C specification 6.2.1§4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p4), the scope of an identifier outside any code block is the whole translation unit:

> Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). **If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit.**

Just for completeness, after saying where the scope *ends*, we must say where the scope *begins* ([C specification 6.2.1§7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p7)):

> Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.

Comment: If the enumeration were unnamed, could you still use the enumerators (e.g. `chck`) in any code? Your example would continue to work but you could only assign integers to `type` (which kind of defeats the purpose of an enumeration), right?

Comment: I don't think the block scope passage you highlighted is the right quote (that refers to a block of code, if I'm not mistaken). Apart from that: Isn't PSkocik's answer correct that a tagged enum is actually visible outside the struct definition it is defined in?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Maybe [this](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p7) ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. And remember, a struct definition is not a block; the scope of the enum tag and the enum members *starts* at their point of declaration (inside the struct definition) but extends to the end of the file. The enum members are visible also for non-tagged enums. See https://www.godbolt.org/z/d88rYo. One consequence is that your last sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica verify it on your compiler..

Comment: I did; did you check the godbolt link? I added a cast, https://www.godbolt.org/z/sYaYra

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have to apologize, as I was completely wrong. In fact in my test I compiled by mistake a cpp file in which the nested symbol are actually not visible outside; then I tried to support this evidence misinterpreting the specification. For this reason my last chapter is garbage and I'm about to correct it (if not completely delete it).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thank you again for pointing out this language-lawyer detail that I never really face in years of "real life" because, if I need an `enum`, I usually define it separately.

Comment: No worries. I have never used such an inner enum before.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `enum` type outside the structure, then declare a member variable with that type.

```
typedef enum {
    chck = 0,
    saving = 1
} accountType;

struct bankAcct{
    int amount;
    accountType typeOfAcc   ;
    int balance;
}
```